# How to have an horizontal TListbox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listbox, horizontal-scrolling

I want to know if it's possible to have a TListbox in Delphi with items that are not on top of each other. I want them to be next to each other...

Thanks...

Comment: Something like single line TListView with vsReport style?

Comment: Is this for VCL or FMX?

Comment: Do you mean something more like a horizontal scrolling widget seen on websites?  You could create your own simply with a TScrollbox and then just place the objects you want inside.

Comment: You need to read about [LBS_MULTICOLUMN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb775149) style.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure HorScrollBar(ListBox: TListBox; MaxWidth: Integer);
var
  i, w: Integer;
begin
  if MaxWidth = 0 then
    SendMessage(ListBox.Handle, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, MaxWidth, 0)
  else
  begin
    { get largest item }
    for i := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
      with ListBox do
      begin
        w := Canvas.TextWidth(Items[i]);
        if w > MaxWidth then
          MaxWidth := w;
      end;
    SendMessage(ListBox.Handle, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT,
      MaxWidth + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME), 0);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the listbox Columns property to use multiple columns with a horizontal scrollbar. The trick is to adjust the value of Columns in code as the number of items changes, depending on the width of the listbox and the width of the items, and I suppose the heights too, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a component that will do that for you:
(Extracted from original source in: Rx Library)
(Tested in Delphi 5)

```
unit TextListBox;
{ TextListBox is a TListBox descendant with (auto) horizontal scrollbar added }
{  Note: TListBox already has a (auto) vertical scrollbar }

interface

uses
 Windows, Classes, Messages, StdCtrls, Math;

type
  TTextListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  private
    FMaxWidth: Integer;
    procedure ResetHorizontalExtent;
    procedure SetHorizontalExtent;
    function GetItemWidth(Index: Integer): Integer;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  published
    property Align;
    property BorderStyle;
    property Color;
    property Ctl3D;
    property DragCursor;
    property DragMode;
    property Enabled;
    property ExtendedSelect;
    property Font;
    property IntegralHeight;
    property Anchors;
    property BiDiMode;
    property Constraints;
    property DragKind;
    property ParentBiDiMode;
    property ImeMode;
    property ImeName;
    property ItemHeight;
    property Items;
    property MultiSelect;
    property ParentColor;
    property ParentCtl3D;
    property ParentFont;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property PopupMenu;
    property ShowHint;
    property Sorted;
    property TabOrder;
    property TabStop;
    property TabWidth;
    property Visible;
    property OnClick;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnExit;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnStartDrag;
    property OnContextPopup;
    property OnMouseWheelDown;
    property OnMouseWheelUp;
    property OnEndDock;
    property OnStartDock;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$R TextListBox.res}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TTextListBox]);
end;


procedure TTextListBox.SetHorizontalExtent;
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, FMaxWidth, 0);
end;

function TTextListBox.GetItemWidth(Index: Integer): Integer;
var
  ATabWidth: Longint;
  S: string;
begin
  S := Items[Index] + 'x';
  if TabWidth > 0 then begin
    ATabWidth := Round((TabWidth * Canvas.TextWidth('0')) * 0.25);
    Result := LoWord(GetTabbedTextExtent(Canvas.Handle, @S[1], Length(S), 1, ATabWidth));
  end
  else Result := Canvas.TextWidth(S);
end;

procedure TTextListBox.ResetHorizontalExtent;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  FMaxWidth := 0;
  for I := 0 to Items.Count - 1 do
    FMaxWidth := Max(FMaxWidth, GetItemWidth(I));
  SetHorizontalExtent;
end;

procedure TTextListBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    LB_ADDSTRING, LB_INSERTSTRING:
      begin
        inherited WndProc(Message);
        FMaxWidth := Max(FMaxWidth, GetItemWidth(Message.Result));
        SetHorizontalExtent;
      end;
    LB_DELETESTRING:
      begin
        if GetItemWidth(Message.wParam) >= FMaxWidth then begin
          Perform(WM_HSCROLL, SB_TOP, 0);
          inherited WndProc(Message);
          ResetHorizontalExtent;
        end
        else inherited WndProc(Message);
      end;
    LB_RESETCONTENT:
      begin
        FMaxWidth := 0;
        SetHorizontalExtent;
        Perform(WM_HSCROLL, SB_TOP, 0);
        inherited WndProc(Message);
      end;
    WM_SETFONT:
      begin
        inherited WndProc(Message);
        Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
        ResetHorizontalExtent;
        Exit;
      end;
    else inherited WndProc(Message);
  end;
end;

end.
```